# 1 Solution and Multiple Projects , deployment issue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I am confused about '1 Solution, Multiple Web Projects' problem. I am using Visual studio 2013 , asp.net (c#). Under 1 solution i have a class library and 2 Web projects.

It works well but now when i deploy it on live server then how a user will open these different projects.

[image]

Comment: Before thinking about the live server, you should deploy them on your local/Dev machine and you will get the whole idea

Comment: sorry i don't understand what u are saying

Comment: Deploy those  website on your computer by following this link . http://www.brainbrushups.com/2013/05/how-to-deploy-or-publish-aspnet-website.html. Then you will find answer to your questions.